# Why won't my background image show at all?

Tags: html, css

I've looked for the answer on everyone of questions that are similar to this question but nothing seems to work. Basically I created a test document to test the background image feature as it wasn't working on my main site.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="styles.css" text="type/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    This is a test.
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Nothing shows apart from "This is a test." I have checked to see if the image is in the same place as the styles.css sheet, and it is. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: body {
 background-image: url("image.jpg") no-repeat;
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
    }

I did this and nothing changed.

Comment: You're using `background` shorthand syntax values with the non shorthand property`background-image`. `background-image` takes one value, the image.

Comment: Refer this, it's basic one. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp &&
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score 3):

You can't combine background-repeat in background-image.

```
body {
   background-image: url("image.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally, it's been seriously bugging me.

Answer (score 3):

Use background `background` instead of `background-image` if you are using no-repeat etc.

```
body {
   background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to W3 http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp background-image property **can be attached to the body tag**.

The only reason you don't see it is **no-repeat** in the wrong place - it is the property of **background itself**, not a background image.

So here is the code you should use case you actually do not want to see image repeating:

```css
body {
   background-image: url("image.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your image url is important to give it:
I hope solved with this.

1- in own folder: "./image.jpg"

2- in out folder: "../image.jpg"

3- or root relative path(eg asp.net): "~/pictures/image.jpg"

4- or relative path: "../pictures/image.jpg"

```
body
{
   background-image: url(./image.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```